# how do i make a pause menu in unity using events in unity vr

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, menu, pause

I'm trying to make a pause menu in unity VR I want when I press a button on the controller the menu appears but I don't know how to make the menu appear when the button is pressed [a picture of what I have om the event thing but I most likely did that wrong too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wQk6.png)

Comment: `when I press a button on the controller the menu appears but I don't know how to make the menu appear when the button is pressed` ... Could you elaborate this sentence? ^^ I rather think it currently **disappears** and you would instead of a hardcoded bool `false` rather implement a method for toggling it right?

Comment: what im trying to do is make a pause menu so that when I press the button the menu opens that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way you have set it up currently is that when you click the button it is calling

```
pauseMenu.SetActive(false);
```

thus it will never enable that object.

You rather need a dedicated component like e.g.

```
public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Reference this vis the Inspector in case the PauseMenu is NOT
    // the same object this component is attached to. 
    // Otherwise it will simply use the same object this is attached to
    [SerializeField] private GameObject pauseMenu;

    // Adjust this vis the Inspector
    // Shall the menu initially be active or not?
    [SerializeField] private bool initiallyPaused;

    // Public readonly property so you can make other scripts depend on this
    // e.g. do not handle User input while pause menu is open etc
    public bool IsPaused => pauseMenu.activeSelf;

    // Additionally provide some events yourself so other scripts
    // can add callbacks and react when you enter or exit paused mode
    public UnityEvent onEnterPaused;
    public UnityEvent onExitPaused;
    public UnityEvent<bool> onPauseStateChanged;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        // As fallback use the same object this component is attached to
        if(!pauseMenu) pauseMenu = gameObject;

         SetPauseMode(initiallyPaused);
    }

    // This is the method you want to call vis your event instead
    public void TogglePause()
    {
        // simply invert the active state
        SetPauseMode(!IsPaused);
    }

    private void SetPauseMode (bool pause)
    {
        pauseMenu.SetActive(pause);

        if(pause)
        {
            onEnterPaused.Invoke();
        }
        else
        {
            onExitPaused.Invoke();
        }

        onPauseStateChanged.Invoke(pause);
    }
}
```

Attach this to your pause menu object and in the event reference the `PauseMenu.TogglePause` method instead.

Comment: i did this and it worked on my PC but when I built for android it did not work do you know why that might be?

Comment: @Imbackgaming well how exactly is your event `Left Secondary Activated` invoked?

Comment: sorry im new to this stuff what does that mean?

Comment: I don't know ^^ how are you calling the `TogglePause` method? I thought you reference it now in your event `Left Secondary Activated` ... I have no clue how/where this gets invoked but it seems like it is simply not happening in VR

Comment: it worked when i ran it on pc vr but when  iput it on android it didn't wokr'

Comment: the code says this        if (_globalInputs.LeftPrimaryButtonState.JustActivated)
            {
                LeftPrimaryActivated.Invoke();
            }

Comment: Well I don't know what exactly this is but seemingly it is never true on Android ...